# opencv libraries precompiled for javacv opencv android project

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I am new to android and opencv,and I am going to develop a APP using this code with this link
here

http://geekoverdose.wordpress.com/category/computer-vision/

The sample project says that "you will have to get the opencv libraries precompiled" in here what I want to do for run this code correctly.please consider about this issue. in here it is wanted to consider about opencv installation for android or is there any special thing have to do? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will take a little more effort to "run this code" correctly. In short, JavaCV is a wrapper on top of OpenCV, and you have to compile the OpenCV and correctly move all the shared libraries (.so) to your Android development project etc. Like the original article suggested, you need to go to JavaCV homepage and read the installation instructions.